# Background jobs that run on every request on Heroku and node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, web-worker

I have an app that needs to run a very long process (takes 30-60 seconds for each request). After the processing, the result is then returned to the request as a response. This works fine locally, but it crashes my Heroku instance.

What I'd like to happen instead is:

- User comes on site, request sent to backend
- Backend returns immediately, and kicks off another process/task/job that does the processing
- When the processing ends, the response is returned to the correct user.

I am not sure what all I need for this. Based on an hour-long research, it seems like I can use Redis as a queue and a worker can poll it every x minutes. But what I can't understand is how to figure out which request to send the response to after processing ends.

Is there a sample Express/node.js for this? Any pointers are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Like you found in your research, setting up a worker queue using Redis is a good approach for long running processes. A nice library for this is [kue (https://github.com/learnboost/kue)](https://github.com/learnboost/kue).

When it comes to responding to a request with the results of the job, having an outanding requesting hanging waiting for a response is not a good way to go about it (and may not work, heroku kills requests that have been idle for a certain period of time).

What you could do is when the request is made start the background job and respond to the request right away with job ID. The client can then poll the server for the status of the job, when the job is complete it can then fetch the needed result.

Comment: `kue` is not nice. I haven't found any good solution for nodejs, so it is better to write own queues manager.

Comment: @happy_marmoset Why is kue not nice?

Comment: Will Heroku kill a request initiated from the node js server? For example, calling some AI endpoints can take minutes to respond and they do not offer caching, so node essentially waits for the response. Will Heroku kill these requests?

Answer (score 1):

Kue (from @mattetre's answer) is not maintained anymore. Kue's GitHub page suggests [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) as a good alternative. It is a fast and reliable Redis based queue for Node.js.